# How to make webpack consume files

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

So I use `Typescript` with `Webpack`.

`tsc` compiles everything from `.ts` to `.js` and then I want to use `webpack` to make it usable by the browser. However the problem is that I still have all of these `.js` files lying around from `tsc`.
Is there some way to tell `webpack`:

"Pack all these things into a nice bundle, and destroy them after you're done!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the [typescript loader for webpack.](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader)

The [Configuration section](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#configuration) of that page presents a sample webpack config

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'] // note if using webpack 1 you'd also need a '' in the array as well
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [ // loaders will work with webpack 1 or 2; but will be renamed "rules" in future
      // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
}
```

As a second real world example, here is the appropriate section from my personal webpack.config.js which also sets up babel and (p)react

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['es2015']
                    }
                },
                'ts-loader'
            ]
        }
    ]
},
resolve: {
    modules: [
        __dirname,
        'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['.ts','.tsx','.js'],
    alias: {
        'react': 'preact-compat/dist/preact-compat.js',
        'react-dom': 'preact-compat/dist/preact-compat.js'
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. I recommend using [awesome-typescript-loader](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader) for this purpose.

```
const rootDir = path.resolve(__dirname);
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    boot: [path.resolve(rootDir, 'src', 'boot')]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(rootDir, 'build')
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  }
};
```

If you use 3rd party modules or libraries, it's also recommended to create separate bundle for vendor files and use [webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/). Check out configuration of [webpack-typescript-postcss-universal-starter](https://github.com/dominik791/webpack-typescript-postcss-universal-starter/blob/master/webpack.dev.js) to see how you can easily use it.